# How is data pass through the pipeline from handler to handler netty

Tags: java, networking, netty

I am trying to get a grasp on the netty concepts through the "netty in action" book.

There are a few concepts that are not explained very well or too vague in my opinion. Therefore I thought I would come here for some clear explanation on the topics.

**ChannelPipeline:**

So I have a channel pipeline like this:

```
@Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new decodeHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new encodeHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("timeout", new IdleStateHandler(60, 0, 0));
        pipeline.addLast("handler", handler);
    }
```

With the channelInitializer, conceptually I would have assumed that the process would be in this order:

`decoder -> handler -> encoder`.

Why is the handler last in the pipeline? Is this because the encoder encodes the message and the handler does something to it and pushes it upstream/to the client.

**ChannelHandler:**

This is the most confusing part of the whole netty for me. So, with a decoder the netty book explains the decode parameters as follows:

> This is the only abstract method you have to implement.
> decode() is called with a ByteBuf containing
> incoming data and a List to which decoded messages
> are added. This call is repeated until it is determined
> that no new items have been added to the List or no
> more bytes are readable in the ByteBuf. Then, if the
> List is not empty, its  contents are passed to the next
> handler in the pipeline.

This all makes sense to me. However, the one confusing part is the last sentence. How exactly are contents passed to the next handler? For example I see the ChannelHandlerContext write data as follows:

```java
ctx.channel().alloc().write(response)
```

However, then we also do

```java
out.add(new Response());
```

I don't know why we write to the channel directly, and sometimes add the readable object to the `out` list variable.

So my question is, when do we write to the channel bound to the context (i.e. `ctx.channel().write()` compared to passing the data via the `out` variable. Because I don't see where in the code that the `out` variable is ever passed into the next handler. It just adds the object to it and thats it. The documentation doesn't show how its passed. I understand the pipeline is a two-way linked list. so what code statement increments the pointers down the pipeline. e.g. I would of thought it would be something like this.

```java
decode(){
   //decode message
   //increment pointer of pipeline and pass out variable to next handler (or new pointer location)
}
```

Any help and clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. First question. What decides the order of the handlers in the pipeline?
   When you call `pipeline.addlast()` to add a handler to the pipeline, the handler will be added at the last of the handler chain. That is, the order of the handlers in the chain depends on the order that you add them. So in your example the handler chain is like this:
   `decode -> encode -> timeout -> handler` 
   But in fact there are two special extra handlers in the pipelile: **head handler and tail handler**. So the real order is like:
   `head -> decode -> encode -> timeout -> handler -> tail`
   Another important thing is there are two kinds of handlers in Netty: **ChannelInboundHandler and ChannelOutboundHandler**. `ChannelInboundHandler` handler received bytes and `ChannelOutboundHandler` handler bytes to be written. That is, if the channel received some bytes, the pipeline of the channel will first give the bytes to head handler, and then pass it to next **ChannelInboundHandler** till tail handler. On the other hand, if you want to send a message and do `ctx.channel.write(msg)`, the pipeline will first pass msg to tail handler, and then pass it to previous **ChannelOutboundhandler** till head handler, and head handler will eventually write this msg to destination.
2. Second question. The difference and connection between `ctx.channel().write()` and `out` list variable?
   The `out` list variable is only used in `Decoder` which is a `ChannelInboundHandler`. That means you are dealing with **received message** when you are using `out` variable. However, when you call `ctx.channel().write()`, it means you are writing or sending something to somewhere else (e.g. another channel). So they are two different things.
3. How is object passed to next handler with only adding it to `out` list variable?
   In fact, the method `decode()` does not pass object, it only parse bytes into objects. So when the channel receives a stream of bytes, `decoder.channelRead()` is invoked. It calls `decode(bytes, out)` to help it to parse the bytes. After decoding, if there is something in `out` list, decoder will pass it to next `ChannelInboundHander`. If not, decoder will do nothing. So the process of passing object happens in `channelRead()`, not `decode()`.
   By the way, there is not a pointer or something like this in pipeline, ChannelInboundHandler use `ctx.fireChannelRead(object)` to pass object to next handler.